CrewAI tool is caching my response. How do I disable it
I have created a custom tool in CrewAI to request human for information. I created this tool as I found it extremely useful to include human in the loop situations.
But I'm facing one issue. Every time the tool is called to elicit some input from the human, the first few times I am able to give in my input. But the times after that, the response gets automatically filled with earlier responses I had given. This doesn't let me give the input that I want to give.
This is how my custom CrewAI tool looks like, I have given this tool to an agent which does some task and in any situation where human input or information is required, it calls this tool.
class AskHumanInputTool(BaseTool):
    name: str = "AskHumanInputTool"
    description: str = ("""This tool is used for asking a human input. 
                           This tool takes a question as an input and ask the input. 
                           The tool return a the answer received.""")

    def _run(self, question_for_human: str) -> str:
        human_input = input(question_for_human)
        return human_input

I have not implemented any caching mechanism for tools. I have also set cache=False in my Crew. How do I solve this issue?
I'm not sure if it is because of the __pycache__ folder being generated that caches the input responses
How do I solve this issue? I am trying to build a Multi Agent System.

You need to implement the cache_function in your tool. By default it is a lambda function that always returns True. Just add the following to your AskHumanInputTool and the caching should be gone:
def cache_function(*args):
    return False

